# Fill in missing hours in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains hourly data:

```
area     date         hour      output
H1       2018-07-01   07:00:00  150
H1       2018-07-01   08:00:00  150
H1       2018-07-01   09:00:00  100
H1       2018-07-01   11:00:00  150
H2       2018-07-01   09:00:00  100
H2       2018-07-01   10:00:00   50
H2       2018-07-01   11:00:00   50
H2       2018-07-01   12:00:00  150
```

but the data only contains row for the hours when there was output, how can I fill in the missing hours for each area with output 0? For example add two rows for H1:

```
area     date         hour      output
H1       2018-07-01   10:00:00  0
H1       2018-07-01   12:00:00  0
```

I can assume that the min and max hour for all areas are the beginning and end of the sample period (in this case 7:00:00 and 12:00:00)

Right now, I'm creating a dataframe containing all the hours from 7:00 to 12:00 for each area and then doing a merge of my data with that dataframe, and then filling the NaN with 0s. This is very slow as my data set can have millions of rows.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: you can try it with `df.fillna(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check `resample` with `groupby`

```
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df.date+' '+df.hour)# combine hour and date to datetime 

df.drop(['date','hour'],inplace=True,axis = 1)# drop duplicate infomation
df.groupby('area').\
    apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Datetime').resample('H').mean().fillna(0)).\
      reset_index()
Out[662]: 
  area            Datetime  output
0   H1 2018-07-01 07:00:00   150.0
1   H1 2018-07-01 08:00:00   150.0
2   H1 2018-07-01 09:00:00   100.0
3   H1 2018-07-01 10:00:00     0.0
4   H1 2018-07-01 11:00:00   150.0
5   H2 2018-07-01 09:00:00   100.0
6   H2 2018-07-01 10:00:00    50.0
7   H2 2018-07-01 11:00:00    50.0
8   H2 2018-07-01 12:00:00   150.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a date range of min and max and merge your dataframe with the existing and fill values with null

df

```
    area    date    hour    output
0   H1  2018-07-01 07:00:00 07:00:00    150
1   H1  2018-07-01 08:00:00 08:00:00    150
2   H1  2018-07-01 09:00:00 09:00:00    100
6   H2  2018-07-01 11:00:00 11:00:00    50
7   H2  2018-07-01 12:00:00 12:00:00    150

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df['date'] +' ' + df['hour']).min(),pd.to_datetime(df['date'] +' ' + df['hour']).max(),freq='H'),columns= ['date']).merge(df,on=['date'],how='outer').fillna(0)
df.hour = df.date.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df.date = df.date.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df
```

Out:

```
date    area    hour    output
0   01-07-2018  H1  07:00:00    150.0
1   01-07-2018  H1  08:00:00    150.0
2   01-07-2018  H1  09:00:00    100.0
3   01-07-2018  0   10:00:00    0.0
4   01-07-2018  H2  11:00:00    50.0
5   01-07-2018  H2  12:00:00    150.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by *Wen* works as long as source dates / times are from
a **single** measuring day.

If the source contained readings from **different** days, the result of *resample*
for each area would be from the earliest reading on the first day, up to the latest
reading on the last day, **includding intermediate night hours**, what is
probably not what you want.

Another drawback of this solution is that it does not provide "zero" readings
from the very start of the measuring day, but from the earliest reading.
The same applies to the "final" reading, also not necessarily at the end of
the measuring day.

My solution, free of these drawbacks, is based on the following assumptions:

1. Leave source *date* column, as it will be needed later.
   After *Datetime* is computed, drop only *hour* column.
2. Generate *df_borders* DataFrame containing *NaN* readings for start / end of
   the measuring day, for each area and date, I assumed for *07:00:00* and  *13:00:00*.
3. Add the above *NaN* readings to the main DataFrame and delete duplicates for each
   *area* / *DateTime*. This way, the source data for each area / day contain
   a reading for the exact start / end of each day, either original or added from
   *df_borders*.
4. To avoid "out of working day" readings, groupping must be performed on
   *['area', 'date']*. This is why I left *date* column until now.
5. Now the *date* column is not needed and can be dropped.
6. The last step is to print the result.

Below you have the example program:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')

# Generate df_borders - NaN readings for start / end of each area / date
df_start = df[['area','date']].drop_duplicates()
df_end = df_start.copy()
df_start['hour'] = '07:00:00'
df_end['hour'] = '13:00:00'
df_borders = pd.concat([df_start,df_end])

# Compute Datetime column and drop hour column, for both DataFrames
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df.hour)
df.drop('hour', inplace=True, axis = 1)
df_borders['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_borders.date + ' ' + df_borders.hour)
df_borders.drop('hour', inplace=True, axis = 1)

# Add NaN readings
df = df.append(df_borders, sort=False, ignore_index=True)\
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['area', 'Datetime'])

# Generate the full set of readings
df = df.groupby(['area', 'date'])\
    .apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Datetime').resample('H').mean().fillna(0))\
    .reset_index()
df.drop('date', inplace=True, axis = 1)

# Result
print(df)
```

Some parts are a copy of the solution by *Wen*, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

For source data:

```
area,date,hour,output
H1,2018-07-01,07:00:00,150
H1,2018-07-01,08:00:00,120
H1,2018-07-01,09:00:00,90
H1,2018-07-01,11:00:00,130
H2,2018-07-01,09:00:00,110
H2,2018-07-01,10:00:00,50
H2,2018-07-01,11:00:00,80
H2,2018-07-01,12:00:00,110
H2,2018-07-02,08:00:00,40
H2,2018-07-02,09:00:00,65
H2,2018-07-02,11:00:00,95
H2,2018-07-02,12:00:00,45
```

it prints:

```
   area            Datetime  output
0    H1 2018-07-01 07:00:00   150.0
1    H1 2018-07-01 08:00:00   120.0
2    H1 2018-07-01 09:00:00    90.0
3    H1 2018-07-01 10:00:00     0.0
4    H1 2018-07-01 11:00:00   130.0
5    H1 2018-07-01 12:00:00     0.0
6    H1 2018-07-01 13:00:00     0.0
7    H2 2018-07-01 07:00:00     0.0
8    H2 2018-07-01 08:00:00     0.0
9    H2 2018-07-01 09:00:00   110.0
10   H2 2018-07-01 10:00:00    50.0
11   H2 2018-07-01 11:00:00    80.0
12   H2 2018-07-01 12:00:00   110.0
13   H2 2018-07-01 13:00:00     0.0
14   H2 2018-07-02 07:00:00     0.0
15   H2 2018-07-02 08:00:00    40.0
16   H2 2018-07-02 09:00:00    65.0
17   H2 2018-07-02 10:00:00     0.0
18   H2 2018-07-02 11:00:00    95.0
19   H2 2018-07-02 12:00:00    45.0
20   H2 2018-07-02 13:00:00     0.0
```

As required, a series of 7 readings, for 3 area / date pairs.