# Filling in missing hours in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
Date_NZST   Time_NZST   Radiation_Amount_MJ/m2
5/08/2011   0:00                     0
5/08/2011   1:00                     0
5/08/2011   2:00                     0
5/08/2011   3:00                     0
5/08/2011   4:00                     0
5/08/2011   5:00                     0
5/08/2011   6:00                     0
5/08/2011   7:00                     0
5/08/2011   8:00                     0
5/08/2011   9:00                     0.37
5/08/2011   10:00                    0.41
5/08/2011   11:00                    1.34
5/08/2011   12:00                    0.87
5/08/2011   14:00                    1.69
5/08/2011   15:00                    1.53
5/08/2011   16:00                    1.14
5/08/2011   17:00                    0.63
5/08/2011   18:00                    0.08
5/08/2011   19:00                    0
5/08/2011   20:00                    0
5/08/2011   21:00                    0
5/08/2011   22:00                    0
5/08/2011   23:00                    0
```

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains hourly measurements of solar irradiance everyday for a year. It has 3 columns, Date_NZST, Time_NZST and Radiation_Amount_MJ/m2.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically find all missing hours, generate a row for that missing hour and fill it with a - symbol in the Radiation_Amount_MJ/m2 column. For example, hour 13:00 is missing so I'd like to make row between the 12:00 and 14:00 rows with the correct date and fill the Radiation_Amount_MJ/m2 column with a -. All dates are present, just some hours are missing.

```
5/08/2011   11:00                    1.34
5/08/2011   12:00                    0.87
5/08/2011   13:00                     -
5/08/2011   14:00                    1.69
5/08/2011   15:00                    1.53
```

I've been doing this in Excel but this is a very tedious process and there could be hundreds of missing points. I've resorted to trying to do it using the Pandas library in Python and I saw this thread ([Fill in missing hours in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409712/fill-in-missing-hours-in-a-pandas-dataframe)) and I tried to alter the answer code to fit my data but I got really confused by the line

```
df.groupby('area').\
    apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Datetime').resample('H').mean().fillna(0)).\
      reset_index()'
```

and how to repurpose it to my data. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create a `datetime` index which contains the date + time with `pd.to_datetime`.

Then we use `resample` to get hourly data, and use `fillna` to fill the missing vallues with a `-`:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date_NZST'] + ' ' + df['Time_NZST']), inplace=True)
df = df.drop(columns=['Date_NZST', 'Time_NZST'])

df = df.resample('H').first().fillna('-')
```

**Output**

```
                   Radiation_Amount_MJ/m2
2011-05-08 00:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 01:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 02:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 03:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 04:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 05:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 06:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 07:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 08:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 09:00:00                   0.37
2011-05-08 10:00:00                   0.41
2011-05-08 11:00:00                   1.34
2011-05-08 12:00:00                   0.87
2011-05-08 13:00:00                      -
2011-05-08 14:00:00                   1.69
2011-05-08 15:00:00                   1.53
2011-05-08 16:00:00                   1.14
2011-05-08 17:00:00                   0.63
2011-05-08 18:00:00                   0.08
2011-05-08 19:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 20:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 21:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 22:00:00                      0
2011-05-08 23:00:00                      0
```

If you want the datetime out of your index use `df.reset_index()`

---

**Note**, by filling in `-` in a numeric column, it gets converted to `object` type.