# Filling in missing hourly data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, missing-data

I have a dataframe containing time series with hourly measurements with the following structure: *name*, *time*, *output*. For each *name* the measurements come from more or less the same time period. I am trying to fill in the missing values, such that for each day all 24h appear in the *time* column.

So I'm expecting a table like this:

```
 name  time                   output 
 x     2018-02-22 00:00:00    100 
       ...                    
 x     2018-02-22 23:00:00    200 
 x     2018-02-24 00:00:00    300 
       ...                    
 x     2018-02-24 23:00:00    300 
 y     2018-02-22 00:00:00    100 
       ...                   
 y     2018-02-22 23:00:00    200 
 y     2018-02-25 00:00:00    300 
       ...                         
 y     2018-02-25 23:00:00    300
```

For this I groupby *name* and then try to apply a custom function that adds the missing timestamps in the corresponding dataframe.

```
def add_missing_hours(df):
    start_date = df.time.iloc[0].date()
    end_date = df.time.iloc[-1].date()
    dates_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = '1H')
    new_dates = set(dates_range) - set(df.time)
    name = df["name"].iloc[0]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'GSRN':[name]*len(new_dates), 'time': new_dates}))
    return df
```

For some reason the *name* column is dropped when I create the DataFrame, but I can't understand why. Does anyone know why or have a better idea how to fill in the missing timestamps?

Edit 1:

This is different than the [question here][1] because they didn't need all 24 values/day -- resampling between 2pm and 10pm will only give the values in between.

Edit 2:

I found a (not great) solution by creating a multi index with all name-timestamps pairs and combining with the table. Code below for anyone interested, but still interested in a better solution:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.combine(df.time.min().date(),datetime.time(0, 0))
end_date = datetime.datetime.combine(df.time.max().date(),datetime.time(23, 0))
new_idx = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = '1H')

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['name'].unique(),new_idx], names=('name','time'))
df_complete = pd.DataFrame(index=mux).reset_index().combine_first(df)
df_complete = df_complete.groupby(["name",df_complete.time.dt.date]).filter(lambda g: (g["output"].count() == 0))
```

The last line removes any days that were completely missing for the specific *name* in the initial dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill in missing hours in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409712/fill-in-missing-hours-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks, but not quite, because resampling doesn't necessarily give the full 24h; for example if the first measurement of the day is at 2pm, resampling will ignore the first part of the day.

Answer (score 0):

try:

1st create dataframe starting from min date to max date with hour as an interval. Then concatenate them together.

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
min_date = df.time.min()
max_date = df.time.max()
dates_range = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date, freq = '1H')
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df3=pd.DataFrame(dates_range).set_index(0)
df4 = df3.join(df)
```

---

**df4:**

```
                   name output
2018-02-22 00:00:00 x   100.0
2018-02-22 00:00:00 y   100.0
2018-02-22 01:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-22 02:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-22 03:00:00 NaN NaN
... ... ...
2018-02-25 19:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-25 20:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-25 21:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-25 22:00:00 NaN NaN
2018-02-25 23:00:00 y   300.0
98 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This doesn't have the correspondence between name, timestamp and output - the name column shouldn't be empty, because I'm filling in the missing values for specific names.

Comment: @user88120: use `df3.join(df)`